# processing programming language: imports sound and video files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, processing

I am not professional in Linux programming, but I have a problem with processing programming language:

There are 2 media files (audio and video), and I would like to import theese in a program. My attempts are that:

```
    imports processing.sound.*;
    imports processing.video.*;

void setup(){
SoundFile soundFile = new SoundFile(this, "soundfile.mp3");
Movie videoFile = new Movie(this, "videofile.mp4");
}
```

When I add the SoundFile objects, the problem is occuring under the runtime:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
>   what(): RtApiAlsa::probeDeviceOpen: pcm device (hw:0,3) won't open for input.
>   Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
>   For more information, read revisions.txt and Help → Troubleshooting.

When I add the Movie objects, the problem is occuring under the runtime:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'gst_date_get_type': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.800.0: undefined symbol: gst_date_get_type
>   A library relies on native code that's not available.
>   Or only works properly when the sketch is run as a 32-bit application.

My question is: How to fix theese problems?

Thank you for answer!
W.

Comment: What version of Processing are you using?

Comment: The version is: 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Googling your first error leads me to this related question: [How can I solve a conflict between openFrameworks and other audio applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400950/how-can-i-solve-a-conflict-between-openframeworks-and-other-audio-applications)

Apparently that error is caused by your having two sound cards, and Processing is trying to open the wrong one. (More accurately, the system default is set to the wrong one.) To fix this problem, you have to reassign your default sound card to the correct one.

Your second error is caused by a native library not loading correctly, or loading the incorrect native library. You might want to make sure that the native library is compatible with your linux version.

More broadly, these errors aren't really specific to Processing. They seem to be more about linux setup. So you might have better luck asking a question in a linux tag.